# Как пишется самая сильная комбинация покера?

Tags: орфография, дефис, слитно-раздельно-дефис, раздельно, слитно

Картёжники и филологи, у меня к вам новый вопрос... Как пишется покерная комбинация «флеш(-)рояль»? Слитно, дефис или вовсе врозь?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: ***флеш-рояль***

Здесь нет никаких принципиальных изменений по сравнению с комбинацией ***стрит-флеш***. Два иноязычных форманта соединены **дефисом** (это стандартная форма для таких слов). Нарицательное существительное пишется со строчной буквы.

Флеш-рояль (англ. royal flush — «королевская масть»): в зависимости от региона принято считать **флеш-рояль** либо отдельной комбинацией, либо частным случаем **стрит-флеша**. Состоит он из 5 старших карт одной масти, начинающихся с туза, например: Т♥ К♥ Д♥ В♥ 10♥ Является самой сильной комбинацией в игре. [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Покер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80)